# Error: NJS-098: 16 positional bind values are required but 5 were provided

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-oracledb

I am facing below error while executing sql query mentioned in the code snippet.
I am already providing all required bind parameters but not able to understand why I need to pass them repeatedly.
[Official documentation](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind-by-name) also mentions that bind parameters needs to appear only once in bind object even if it is used many times in sql.

> Error: NJS-098: 16 positional bind values are required but 5 were provided

Below are the node and oracledb versions I am using.

> node version - 20.10.0
> oracledb version - 6.3.0

```js
import { dashboardRecord, dashboardRecordsRequest, dashboardRecordsResponse } from "datamodel/dashboard/dashboard";
import { logger } from "logger/logger";
import * as OracleDB from "oracledb";

export async function getActiveRequestRecords(dashboardRecordsRequest: dashboardRecordsRequest): Promise<dashboardRecordsResponse> {
    const p_entityname: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN, val: dashboardRecordsRequest.entityName, type: OracleDB.STRING };
    const p_sortby: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN, val: dashboardRecordsRequest.sortBy, type: OracleDB.STRING };
    const p_sortOrder: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN, val: dashboardRecordsRequest.sortOrder, type: OracleDB.STRING };
    const p_startindex: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN, val: dashboardRecordsRequest.startIndex, type: OracleDB.NUMBER };
    const p_pagesize: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_IN, val: dashboardRecordsRequest.pageSize, type: OracleDB.NUMBER };
    const p_totalrecords: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_OUT, type: OracleDB.NUMBER };
    const p_activerecords: OracleDB.BindParameter = { dir: OracleDB.BIND_OUT, type: OracleDB.CURSOR };
    const bindParams: OracleDB.BindParameter[] = [
        p_entityname,
        p_sortby,
        p_sortOrder,
        p_startindex,
        p_pagesize,
        p_totalrecords,
        p_activerecords
    ];
    const execOptions: OracleDB.ExecuteOptions = { outFormat: OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT, resultSet: true };

    const recordsSQL: string = `SELECT
                                    requestnumber,
                                    requeststatus,
                                    requestor,
                                    pendingwith,
                                    processtype,
                                    actiondate
                                FROM
                                    requests
                                WHERE
                                    ( ( upper(:p_entityname) = 'HR'
                                            AND processtype IN ( 'PROCTYPE1', 'PROCTYPE2' ) )
                                        OR ( upper(:p_entityname) = 'MANAGER'
                                            AND processtype NOT IN ( 'PROCTYPE1', 'PROCTYPE2' ) ) )
                                        AND AND upper(requeststatus) = 'PENDINGAPPROVAL'
                                ORDER BY
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'desc' AND lower(:p_sortby) = 'requestnumber' THEN requestnumber END ) DESC,
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'asc' AND lower(:p_sortby) = 'requestnumber' THEN requestnumber END ) ASC,
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'desc' AND lower(:p_sortby) = 'processtype' THEN processtype END ) DESC,    
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'asc' AND lower(:p_sortby) = 'processtype' THEN processtype END ) ASC,    
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'desc' AND lower(:p_sortby) =  'actiondate' THEN actiondate END ) DESC,
                                    ( CASE WHEN lower(:p_sortorder) = 'asc' AND lower(:p_sortby) =  'actiondate' THEN actiondate END ) ASC
                                OFFSET :p_startindex ROWS FETCH NEXT :p_pagesize ROWS ONLY`;

    try {
        const dbConnection = await OracleDB.getConnection('requestpool');
        const recordsResult = await dbConnection.execute(recordsSQL, bindParams, execOptions);
        const recordsResultSet = await recordsResult.resultSet?.getRows();
        console.log(recordsResultSet);
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```